# How are Ingress Top Agents chosen

Tags: ingress

Is it the total MU that agent has contributed in the overall cycle that gets an agent in the Top Agents list or is there some other logic behind the ranking system? Not sure if this question was asked before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Top agents are calculated based on their total MU throughout the entire cycle. It's being refreshed every CP. Top agents list doesn't show the team's success. It's a total personal list. If a player creates the same field 10 times during the cycle but this field doesn't stand up at the end of any checkpoint this player will be listed accordingly on the top agents list but the team won't get any points from those fields

Comment: So if that user created 10 fields and none of them stood up at each CP we know the team wont get any points from the fields but what happens to the users rank in the list? Does he/she go up in the ranks or stay at the same rank?

Comment: As I've said in my answer that agent "will be listed accordingly on the top agents list" which means, yes, they will go up in the ranks.